# Generic delegate type error

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

lets say i have the next Course class:

```
class Course
    {
        internal Student myStudent { get; set; }
        internal string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0, -5} {1, -15} {2}", Name, myStudent.Name, string.Join(" ", myStudent.Grade));
        }
        internal class Student
        {
            internal string Name { get; set; }
            internal List<int?> Grade { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

and i want in the main use in a generic delegate, once for int and once for string:

```
SomeDelegate<string> d1 = new SomeDelegate<string>(course => course.Name);
SomeDelegate<int> d2 = new SomeDelegate<int>(course => (int)course.myStudent.Grade.DefaultIfEmpty(null).Average());
```

The generic delegate is:

```
delegate T SomeDelegate<T>(T param);
```

but i get errors.

> string does not contain a definition for 'Name'....

Why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: `T` is both the type of the argument and the return type of your delegate, so in `d1`, `course` is a `string` (and in `d2`, it's an `int`). You'll probably want to use `Func<Course, string>` (and `Func<Course, int>`) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your delegate definition requires that the type of the input parameter and the output be the same.  In your case, you are trying to pass in an object with a `Name` property and return a string, which violates the signature of your delegate.

Change your delegate to

```
delegate TOut SomeDelegate<TIn, TOut>(Tin param);
```

or use the built-in [`Func` delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3).

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need a pair of delegates.  The issue here is that we have two use cases you are wanting to use:

```
delegate T SomeDelegate<T>(T param);
```

Above is a simple delegate, which means you are passing in a `T`, not a lambda that returns a `T`.  In this case you would call it like this: `new SomeDelegate<string>(course.Name)`

```
delegate T SomeDelegate<T>(Func<T> param);
```

Above is a slightly more complex delegate, which means you are passing in a function that evaluates to `T` when it is done.  Lambdas are pretty good at handling that.  In this case you would call it like this: `new SomeDelegate<string>(course => course.Name)`

You can read more about lambdas, expressions, etc. here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx